# Elixir - Capture value from lambda

Tags: elixir

Consider the following code snippet:

```
def capture
    Functor.function(fn(value) -> ??? end)
    ???
end
```

- Assume that the lambda DOES get called exactly once for sure

What would be the preferred way to capture the first argument of the lambda `fn(value)` in a way that it can be the return of `capture` method?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You want to return `value` from `capture`? What if that fn isn't called even once? and what if that fn is called more than once?

Comment: @Dogbert Tried to clarify on the issues you raised, thanks for the feedback! Loved your nick ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need some form of mutable state here. The simplest way is to use `Agent`:

```
defmodule Functor do
  def function(f) do
    f.(:hey)
  end

  def capture do
    {:ok, agent} = Agent.start_link(fn -> nil end)
    Functor.function(fn(value) ->
      Agent.update(agent, fn _ -> value end)
    end)
    Agent.get(agent, &(&1))
  end
end

IO.inspect Functor.capture()
```

Output:

```
:hey
```

Some things to note:

If the fn is never called, you'll get the initial value of the Agent (`nil` in the code above).

If the fn is called more than once, you'll get the value of the last call. With a little modification, you can even capture *all* values, if that's what you want.

---

Edit: Since you mentioned you're only using this for testing, there's another, much more concise way. Send a message to yourself from the fn and assert with `assert_receive`:

```
test "the truth" do
  pid = self()
  Functor.function(&send(pid, &1))
  assert_receive :hey
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I was already using agent but wanted to be sure about the preferred way to do that. We are currently using this technique for writing unit-tests only - It is of my understanding that we will rarely use this on production.

Comment: Please see my edit for a better/shorter way if this is only for testing!

Comment: Thank you for the update, indeed for simple cases assert_receive would be the preferred solution. ;)